# wget not behaving via IPC::Open3 vs bash

Tags: perl, ipc, wget

I'm trying to stream a file from a remote website to a local command and am running into some problems when trying to detect errors.

The code looks something like this:

```
use IPC::Open3;

my @cmd = ('wget','-O','-','http://10.10.1.72/index.php');#any website will do here

my ($wget_pid,$wget_in,$wget_out,$wget_err);
if (!($wget_pid = open3($wget_in,$wget_out,$wget_err,@cmd))){
    print STDERR "failed to run open3\n";
    exit(1)
}
close($wget_in);
my @wget_outs = <$wget_out>;
my @wget_errs = <$wget_err>;
print STDERR "wget stderr: ".join('',@wget_errs);
#page and errors outputted on the next line, seems wrong
print STDERR "wget stdout: ".join('',@wget_outs);

#clean up after this, not shown is running the filtering command, closing and waitpid'ing
```

When I run that wget command directly from the command-line and redirect stderr to a file, something sane happens - the stdout will be the downloaded page, the stderr will contain the info about opening the given page.

```
wget -O - http://10.10.1.72/index.php 2> stderr_test_file
```

**When I run wget via open3, I'm getting both the page and the info mixed together in stdout.  What I expect is the loaded page in one stream and STDERR from wget in another.**

I can see I've simplified the code to the point where it's not clear why I want to use open3, but the general plan is that I wanted to stream stdout to another filtering program as I received it, and then at the end I was going to read the stderr from both wget and the filtering program to determine what, if anything went wrong.

  Other important things:
- I was trying to avoid writing the wget'd data to a file, then filtering that file to another file, then reading the output.
- It's key that I be able to see what went wrong, not just reading $? >> 8 (i.e. I have to tell the user, hey, that IP address is wrong, or isn't the right kind of website, or whatever).
- Finally, I'm choosing system/open3/exec over other perl-isms (i.e. backticks) because some of the input is provided by untrustworthy users.

Comment: @DVK - I'm not sure what you mean?  feed wget on STDIN?  I'm not sure there's anything I need to give it?

Comment: OK, tried that, via a bash shell, stdout and stderr are still separable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing an undefined value as the error handle argument to open3, and as [`IPC::Open3`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IPC::Open3) says:

> If CHLD_ERR is false, or the same file descriptor as CHLD_OUT, then STDOUT and STDERR of the child are on the same filehandle **(this means that an autovivified lexical cannot be used for the STDERR filehandle**, see SYNOPSIS) ...

The workaround is to initialize `$wget_err` to something before calling `open3`:

```
my ($wget_pid, $wget_in, $wget_out, $wget_err);
use Symbol qw(gensym);
$wget_err = gensym();
if (!$wget_pid = open3( ... ) ) { ...
```

Comment: aaand, that's what I get for not actually RTFM... I read the Open2 docs, then realized I needed STDERR later in the process, and didn't read past the first line of the Open3 docs.